# UCWA OAuth token invalid when creating application

Tags: azure-active-directory, ucwa

I am trying to use ucwa by authenticating users with Azure ID.
I have tried to follow these informations : [Authentication using Azure AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/authenticationusingazuread)

Some steps didn't function verry well but I managed to get the application ressource link after resending an autodiscovery request with the bearer token.

The bearer token works when I send a get request to https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root/oauth/user.
So I receive a answer like this one :

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
 "_links":{
 "self":{"href":"https://webdirX.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/user"},
 "applications":{"href":"https://webpoolXY.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications"}
 }
}`

So I try to do a post request like this one :

`POST https://webpoolXY.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <access-token>
...
{
 "UserAgent":"UCWA Samples",
 "EndpointId":"a917c6f4-976c-4cf3-847d-cdfffa28ccdf",
 "Culture":"en-US",
}`

But I have a `403 Forbidden` answer, with 
`X-Ms-diagnostics:28055;source="DB41E07FES15.infra.lync.com";reason="The OAuth token is invalid.";faultcode="wsse:FailedAuthentication"`

I use the same Bearer access-token for this request. Am I supposed to get a new token ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to get a new token to access the applications resource before you can successfully POST to it.

In your example, pass https://webpoolXY.infra.lync.com/ as the resource to Azure AD and use the resulting token to perform your POST request.

I've created a [C#-based sample application](https://github.com/tamhinsf/ucwa-sfbo-console) that performs UCWA Autodiscovery along with application creation, meeting create/list/delete, and presence management you can take a look at as a reference.

Comment: Well thank you for the sample and the response.
I now try with a new bearer token but I get this response : {"code":"UnsupportedMediaType","message":"The mode of communication you/re
trying to use isn/t supported with this person or meeting."}

Comment: You might've noticed this in my code, but calls to the application resources need to have "application/json" set in the accept headers.  For example:     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

Comment: I have tried with both 'accept' and 'content-type' headers set to 'application/json' but I still get the same error..

Comment: Try encoding the contents as well.  You'd do this in C# as so                var httpResponseMessage =
                httpClient.PostAsync(ucwaApplicationsRootUri, new StringContent(createUcwaPostData, Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json")).Result;